# flash player security

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I can run the following locally on my own machine without problem (and also loaded through a test.html.  However it will not load if I download it from a test webhost I'm using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    xmlns="*" layout="absolute"
    >

    <mx:SWFLoader id="swfloader" source="colorpickerexample.swf"  height="200" />

</mx:Application>
```

The strange thing is, I have a much much more complex flex app with all sorts of swfloaders in it which I can download from the test server and run on my local machine without problem.
I take it this may have something to do with crossdomain.xml, or trust files or some other aspect of flash player security which I admit I have never properly grasped.  So would anyone mind telling me what the flash player is balking about when I try to download and run the above from a test web server.

Answer (score 0):

The source passed to the SWFLoader is a relative path.  When you download the SWF to your local machine do you have the colorpickerexample.swf in the same directory?

Comment: well there's a colorpickerexample.swf on the webserver in the same direcory as the above example.  It should be downloaded from there, right?

Comment: As far as ther complex flex app I have that works, the only difference I can think of is that the complex app gets the names of the swf's out of an xml file (i.e. not hardcoded into the SWFLoaders.)

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, it was case-sensivity - the file name is ColorPickerExample.swf, not colorpickerexample.swf

I don't understand this either, as that's not an issue with the local file system, in case anyone can inform me what aspect is case sensitive here.

Comment: If your local filesystem is NTFS (Windows), that's case-insensitive. If your server's filesystem is ext3 (Linux), that's case-sensitive.